# Help with tables normalization for delivery system

Tags: mysql, normalization

i have a task to design a SQL database to represent a "delivery". I've been able to solve most of the needs, however i have doubts with one relationship:

A delivery has an origin and a destination address, this addresses can be either a home or a storage place (2 homes, 2 storages, home and storage, storage and home).

If it a is home, it's just a plain address, however if it is a storage we need some extra configuration columns.

In practice this is the problem:

- 1 storage -> 1 address (1 storage has only 1 address)
- 1 delivery -> 2 addresses -> where each address can be either a home or a storage.

I came up with a solution but i would like to know another persons opinion.

```
storage
id
code
name
company_id
address_id

--
address
id
street_name
street_no
city
contact_name
contact_phone
storage_id (NULLABLE)

--
delivery
id
origin_address_id (FK address
destination_address_id (FK address)
```

I have doubts because it looks like a storage could have multiple addresses, and i don't know whether adding two address columns in the delivery table goes against the normal forms.

The idea is:

- When creating a delivery they can send me a storage id for origin/destination.
- I would then look in storage table to retrieve it's address.
- Finally, i create a delivery with storage->address_id as the origin/destination column in the delivery table.

Comment: Right now everything can have anything because you have no keys.  Ditch the `Id`s and read up on subtypes (sounds like you need a `Location` entity): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes

Comment: "i don't know whether adding two address columns in the delivery table goes against the normal forms" Why don't you know? What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method given what? [ask] [Help] PS You have a case of subtyping/inheritance. PS ["1NF" has no agreed meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) (All involve replacing some table(s) with parameterized structure by some table(s) with a column per parameter.) What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Turn things around.

Table `addresses` needs a `delivery_id`.  Ditto for the table `storage`.

If you want to avoid having multiple rows for addresses or storages, then have two "many-to-many" tables to map between `delivery_id` and the other tables.

Tables:

- `Deliveries`:  `delivery_id`, etc
- `map1`:  `delivery_id` and `address_id`; no other columns.
- `map2`:  `delivery_id` and `storage_id`; no other columns.
- `Addresses`:  `address_id`, etc.
- `Storages`:  `storage_id`, etc.

To select the info for one delivery, you might have 5 tables `JOINed` together.